# Mongoose nested query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, postman

Contact Model has an userID and a nested document as contacts

```
Contact.findOne({userId : req.userData.userId}).exec().then( doc =>{
    console.log(doc);
    res.status(200).json({doc})
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json({error : err})
})
```

And this code output is like that:

```
{
"doc": {
    "_id": "5fd4c77508f14a1e108c8788",
    "userId": "5fd4c77508f14a1e108c8787",
    "contacts": [
        {
            "_id": "5fd4e9cc08f14a1e108c8789",
            "name": "muaz",
            "number": 123415123,
            "contactImage": "uploads\\2020-12-12T16-03-24.588Zqweqqq.png"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5fd4ea102502ab1130549bbb",
            "name": "muazs",
            "number": 123415123,
            "contactImage": "uploads\\2020-12-12T16-04-32.561Zqweqqq.png"
        }]}
```

And I get a contact id from request (req.params.userId).

For example: When I get a request as **req.param.userId = 5fd4e9cc08f14a1e108c8789**

**I want to send response like that:**

```
{
        "_id": "5fd4e9cc08f14a1e108c8789",
        "name": "muaz",
        "number": 123415123,
        "contactImage": "uploads\\2020-12-12T16-03-24.588Zqweqqq.png"
    }
```

How can I get this contact with model find methods?

Comment: I don t understand the part with the id, so you have an id in your request and also in your database entry ?

Comment: most dateiled question in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65267374/mongoose-nested-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const {userId}=req.params;

Contact.findOne({"contacts._id":userId}, {contacts:{$elemMatch:{_id:userId}})
.then(data=>res.send(data.contacts[0]))
.catch(err=>res.send("Not found!"))
```

This will return only the matched user details based on the userId stored as _id, exactly what you want.